# What is the best way to change the value of a certain row and column in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to change the value of a row and a column to X once the user inputs the number of the row and the column that he wanted to reserve but I don't know how to do it or what code to use. I thought of using `Arrays.fill` but it fills the entire table.

```
System.out.println("Bus Seat Reservation:");
System.out.println("         Col 1:    Col: 2    Col 3:    Col 4:  ");

String[][] seat = {{"Row 1: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 2: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 3: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 4: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 5: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 6: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 7: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 8: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 9: |*", "          *", "         *", "         *"},
                   {"Row 10:|*", "          *", "         *", "         *"}};

for (int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < seat[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(seat[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.print("Enter row and column to reserve separated by space (Enter a negative number to exit: ");
int reserve = keyboard.nextInt();
```

This is what I have accomplished so far.

Comment: You might need to rethink the `seat` array. Remove all the text. That can be added when printing. Just store the seat data: `char [][] seat = {{'*','*','*'},{'*','*','*'},{'*','*','*'},...};` And then set a seat as taken with something like `seat[row][col] = 'X';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read row no and column no from user . ie

```
int row1 = reader.nextInt();
int col1 = reader.nextInt();
```

Then assign the value

```
seat[row1-1][col1-1] = "X";
```

Whole code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReservationSeat {

    private static void display(String[][] table,String[] rows,String[] columns){
        Arrays.stream(columns).forEach(System.out::print);
        for(int row = 0; row < table.length; row++){

            System.out.print(rows[row]+"\t\t|");
            for(int col = 0; col < table[row].length; col++){
                System.out.print("\t\t" + table[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] columnName = { "\t\t\t   Col 1\t",  "Col 2\t",  "Col 3\t",  "Col 4\t\n" };
        String[] rowName = { "Row 1 ", "Row 2 ", "Row 3 ", "Row 4 ", "Row 5 ", "Row 6 ", "Row 7 ", "Row 8 ", "Row 9 ", "Row 10 "};
        String [][] seat = {
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"*", "*","*", "*"}

        };

        display(seat,rowName,columnName);
        System.out.print("Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space (Enter a negative number to exit): ");
        int rowNo = reader.nextInt();
        int colNo = reader.nextInt();
        seat[rowNo-1][colNo-1] = "X";
        int[][] test1 = new int[rowNo][colNo];
        display(seat,rowName,columnName);
    }
}
```

Comment: String arrays `columns` and `Rows` (the latter breaking Java naming convention) seem to be redundant.  It would be enough to provide the row number and column number to generate the 2D array.

Comment: It showed this error /SeatReservation.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Arrays.stream(columns).forEach(System.out::print);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class SeatReservation
/SeatReservation.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
           display(seat,Rows,columns);           
                        ^
  symbol:   variable Rows
  location: class SeatReservation
/SeatReservation.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
           display(seat,Rows,columns);       

I'm so dumb im sorry :>

Comment: I think you missed import for java.util.Arrays; just add import java.util.Arrays;